# How to prevent my page render before authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, dom, render

I have an authentication function inserted in all pages I want be only for users. But the HTML get render and later do the authentication. How can I prevent the DOM get render before the authentication proccess?

Comment: Use the `XMLHttpRequest` to verify information is good on the Server, before building or showing the DOM.

Comment: I can do that setting a "display=none" class in the body, removing it when the auth is verified, but the HTML appears in the console while is verifying. Isn't there some method like window.onload, for instance?

Comment: Your HTML is not so important that you should be worry about hiding your structure. Anyone can make their own structure. You should, however, focus on data security. That being said, if you don't want the Client to see the HTML until after a query, then send the HTML from the Server to the Client.

Answer (score 0):

how about code splitting?
Check authentication first,
then asynchronously loads the html code.

```
// auth page
const check =async()=>{
  await authentication();
  
  import("./renderFile.js").then(a => {
    
  });
}

check();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```js
if(authenticated) {window.open(params)}//open whatever page you want
```

and for the new window

```js
if(window.opener === 'bleh') {window.open(params)}//open error page
```

might not be convenient for the user though so try using document.write